# Этимология слова "гопник"

Tags: этимология

Каково происхождение слова "гопник" и что оно означает?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Есть две версии происхождения слова «гопник». По одной оно происходит от жаргонного обозначения грабителя. В словаре Даля упоминается слово «Гоп»

> выражает скачок, прыжок или удар; | междомет. стук, шлеп. Скажешь гоп,
>   как перескочишь! не прежде. Гопать, прыгать, скакать, сигать; гопнуть,
>   прыгнуть или ударить. -ся, шлепнуться, упасть. Гоп или гопки! повелит.
>   прыгни, скакни.

Так как уличные грабители имели обыкновение внезапно нападать («прыгать, наскакивать») на свою жертву, нередко при этом ударяя её, чтобы ошеломить и лишить возможности убежать/сопротвиляться, то их преступление и стали в криминальной среде называть гоп, гопстоп или гоп-скок, а их самих — гопники или гопстопники. Неудивительно, что со временем так стали называть представителей криминализированной части советской, а затем и постсоветской молодёжи, для которых гоп-стоп, т.е. внезапные нападения на случайных прохожих с целью ограбления, был обычной практикой.

Есть и другая версия. Ещё в XIX веке в России существовали «Городские общества призора» (ГОП), т.е. заботы, попечения, при которых имелись приюты для бездомных, калек, сирот и т.д. Тех кто содержался в этих приютах стали называть гопники. Контингент ГОПов был склонен к совершению преступлений, т.ч. слова «гоп» и «гопник» быстро обрели негативный оттенок. Гопами стали называть ночлежки или нахождение в ночлежке, а под гопниками имели в виду опустившихся людей из социальных низов, склонных к бродяжничеству и совершению преступлений. Среди содержавшихся в ГОПах было немало подростков и молодых людей. Неудивительно, что постепенно слово гопник стало ассоциироваться с криминальной частью молодёжи.

В принципе, обе версии друг другу не противоречат. Так что, возможно, они обе правильны.

Comment: Марк, насколько знаю, в дореволюционных источниках слово "гопник" достоверное не фиксируется.

Comment: @behemothus, такая лексика вообще мало фиксируется. А. А. Сидоров, считает, что появилось ещё до революции, что в принципе логично.  [ссылка](http://lib.ru/NEWPROZA/SIDOROV_A/fima_zhemchug.txt)

Comment: Да знаю я. Ято вы мне пересказываете источники, на которые я же давал ссылку? А кто он этот Сидоров?

Comment: @behemothus, Фима Жиганец.  Автор "Словаря блатного и лагерного жаргона, Южная феня"

Comment: Ах, этот... Я и забыл,что он Сидоров. Тогда понятно. У него вообще очень много из пальца высосанного...  Бабель вот не знал, а Фима знает. Ладно, проехали.

Answer (score 1):

**Гопник** - судя по всему от ГОП - "государственное общежитие пролетариата". Так после революции в Питере именовали ночлежки для разного рода люмпенизированного элемента. Можно представить, каким рассадником уголовщины они были. **Гопник** - обитатель такого **ГОПа**.

Связь с уголовным "гоп-стоп" прослеживается, но что тут первично, не берусь утверждать.

А вот политики тут видеть бы не хотелось. Ни пропутинской, ни запутинской.

(+)
Вот тут есть все версии...

http://www.gopniki.net/index.php/istoria-gopnikov/13-istoria/11-otkuda-poshlo-slovo-gopnik.html

Comment: забавно,  а в Вики этой версии  нету. Про  "общество призора" есть,  а  про знаменитые питерские ГОПы - нет...

Comment: Помню, как моя бабушка, видя в квартире беспорядок, повторяла: "Как на гопе... Как на гопе!"

Answer (score 1):

Гопак`Малый академический словарь`
гопак
-а́, м.
Украинская народная пляска, а также музыка к этой пляске.
[Сашка] ухарски топнул ногой и закричал: — Гопака! Раздались подмывающие отчаянные звуки запорожского танца. Скиталец, Огарки.

Гопак`Большая Советская энциклопедия`
Гопак (укр., от гоп — восклицание, произносимое во время танца; отсюда же глаголы гопати — топать, гопкати — прыгать)
украинский народный танец, главным образом мужской. Включает прыжки, присядки, вращения, нередко имеет величавый, героический характер.

Может, от английского hop - прыгать? 
У российских хулиганов есть устойчивая фраза: "совершить прыжок", в значении неожиданно напасть на кого-то, а потом смотаться.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы понять значение слова "гопник", его следует сравнить со словом "жлоб". 
Гопник и жлоб - это вымогатели. Жлоб действует, используя в давлении на незнакомого (в основном) человека недружелюбность, угрозы, силовое давление. Гопник действует, используя в давлении на незнакомого (в основном) человека приятельские отношения. Подходит к незнакомому человеку, в голосе и просьбах приятельские, добрые, заискивающие нотки, просит войти в его положение по-приятельски - попробуй такому откажи!

Answer (score -2):

Гопник от ГОП - государственное общежитие пролетариата. И это единственная правильная версия.

Comment: Единственно правильной была только философия Марксизма-Ленинизма, а все остальное нужно потрудиться доказать.